# Angular 6 ngModel data binding automatically converting uppercase

Tags: css, asp.net-core, angular6

I'm working with angular 6 dashboards. For all forms, I used ngModel to bind data. So Now there is another new requirement. All data must be sent to backend as converting UPPERCASE. Is there any way to convert all data to uppercase in one place??

I put a style to all inputs globally as bellow.

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

But Data is not sent by converting uppercase. ( Only frontend showing uppercase. )

If not Is there an easy way to convert them from the backend. ( Backend is written by .net core )

Comment: I think this can use only for display purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input (ngModelChange)="somethingChanged(input_data)">`
in your html

and in your ts just write the function to convert your input to uppercase

```
somethingChanged(input_data){
new_data=input_data.toUpperCase( )
}
```

Comment: yes, But it is hard to integrate large systems. I want to convert all form data to uppercase. If one form contain 30 inputs we have to implements that for all the inputs.